# PHP / HTML uploading script not working right

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm pretty new in PHP (don't have much HTML experience, too) and I have a question. I have a file upload system which consists of two PHP scripts (see below). In the file upload form a user selects file, saving folder and then uploads. Saving location can be chosen from a drop-down menu which consists of folders in uploading directory. But there's another option in the drop-down menu. If the user chooses the option `other` then a new field comes up (it's done by JavaScript) and the user can insert location manually (for example, a directory doesn't exist and the user wants to make a new one).

But here's a problem: if the user chooses a folder which is predefined everything is OK, but if the user writes a directory name to the field then only folder called `folder` will be created. For example, if the user wants to upload a picture about a flower and no folder called `flower` exists then the user chooses `other` and writes `flower` into the box. Then upload button is clicked and basically PHP should make a new folder called `flower` and upload the picture there. But at the moment, PHP makes a folder called `folder` and for some reason the picture is not uploaded there (it's uploaded nowhere).

My problems with the script:

1. A new folder won't be created. I think it's because I have two values called "folder" but I don't know how to get it work that if "other" is selected then PHP only looks the last value.
2. Even if the folder is created then a file won't be uploaded there for some reason.

I would be really grateful if anyone finds the solution for my problem and helps me to fix it. And don't hesitate to ask for extra information because my English isn't the best and because of this some things can't be understood.

Thanks in advance!

1st file: `file-upload.php`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function Toggle(obj){
var val=obj.value;
if (!obj.m){ obj.m=''; }
if (!obj.m.match(val)){ obj.m+=','+val+','; }
var hide=obj.m.split(',');
for (var zxc0=0;zxc0<hide.length;zxc0++){
if (document.getElementById(hide[zxc0])){
document.getElementById(hide[zxc0]).style.display='none';
}
}
var show=val.split(',');
for (var zxc1=0;zxc1<show.length;zxc1++){
if (document.getElementById(show[zxc1])){
document.getElementById(show[zxc1]).style.display='';
}
}
}

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload</h1>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
<label for="file">File:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <br>
    Tüüp: <select name="folder" value="folder" onchange="Toggle(this);">
<?php  
foreach(glob('/uploadfolder/*',      GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) 
{ 
    $dir = basename($dir); 
    echo '<option value="', $dir, '">', $dir, '</option>'; 
}  
?>
<option value="folder">other</option>
        </select><br> 

<input id="folder" value="Create a new folder" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd file: `upload.php`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload</h1>
<br>

<?php
$dirname  = $folder = $_POST["folder"];
$filename = "/uploadfolder/" . "$dirname" . "/";

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    mkdir("/uploadfolder/" . "$dirname", 0777);
}

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-     officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5120000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Tmp. file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Folder: " . $folder . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("/uploadfolder/$folder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "/uploadfolder/$folder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Saved: " . "" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
     }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload failed";
  }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do the Following Steps**

In file-upload.php, add a name attribute to the text field for the new folder name . Let it be like this,

```
<input id="folder" value="Create a new folder" name="newfolder" style="display:none;">
```

Now in the upload.php file make changes as below,

```
$dirname = $_POST["folder"];
$filename = ("./uploadfolder/" . "$dirname" . "/");
if($dirname=="folder"){$dirname=$_POST["newfolder"];}
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    mkdir("./uploadfolder/" . "$dirname", 0777);
}
```

Use `$dirname` as the folder name through out. So replace `$folder` with `$dirname`

Another thing is, if upload is still not working fine, just use `"./uploadfolder/$folder/"` as base path. Also Give 777 permissions to your workspace. You may use the following command,

```
chmod -R 777 <path_to_uploadfolder>
```

As mentioned by other SOF users, remove `exit;` from the file exist check in the beginning.

Hope you have the answer ! :)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Your post was really helpful, my script is almost working. But there's still one problem. If I choose a folder which already exists as destination everything's fine, file is uploaded into that folder, but if I choose "other" from drop-down menu and then insert folder name manually, for example "travelling", and then I click on "Upload", a folder named "folder" is created. For some reason manually inserted folder name is not processed by PHP. Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: hi mihkel93, the problem is actually with the <option> tag for "other". You are getting value of other from <option> tag and not of the text field. I prefer, you change the value of the Option Tag for "other" via JS when a user hits submit based on the entered value in the text field. or else, set a default value to the other and change it in the server side as i mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> at the moment PHP makes a folder called "folder" and for some reason the picture IS NOT even uploaded there

That's because you have an `exit;` in the following excerpt from the second file:

```
<?php
$dirname = $_POST["folder"];
$filename = ("/uploadfolder/" . "$dirname" . "/");

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    mkdir("/uploadfolder/" . "$dirname", 0777);
    exit;
} else {
}
?>
```

As a result, the script quits as soon as the folder is created.

There are multiple security problems with your script but I won't bother getting into them because this is not the place for security lessons :)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yeah, I know it's not the best script and there are many security problems but the script is used only by me at the moment and it is protected by Apache password.

Answer (score 0):

The line `exit` after the `mkdir` will cause the script to stop executing. If you want to create the folder then continue on to the file upload, you need to remove the `exit` statement. You can also remove the `else` portion of that if, since it's empty ...

```
$dirname  = $folder = $_POST["folder"];
$filename = "/uploadfolder/" . "$dirname" . "/";

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    mkdir("/uploadfolder/" . "$dirname", 0777);
}

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
...
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. But the script is not working still correctly.